# Microsoft Azure Continuous Integration - NodeJs Solution with Grunt "Compile" step

Tags: node.js, azure, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

**Some precursor to my question.**

I might get a bit verbose with details, but I'd just like to ensure that I'm not leaving out anything that might be causing my problem. (I'll append the complete error log at the end of the question. But I don't expect anyone to go too buck wild with it. I'll try summarize as much as I can)

1. I scaffold-ed an AngularJS project using [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/).Using the the `yo angular` command.
2. I then created the `deploy.cmd` & `.deployment` files
3. Pushed it up to my git repository on Bitbucket. (Only commited the root folder files, and the test & app folders)
4. From there, linked it up to Azure via their website quick setup.
5. My build is separated into 2 parts installing grunt and bower (globally) during the deployment, and then installing the grunt packages during the npm package installation
6. Then I'll need to attempt to run `grunt build` as a `POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION`

**package.json** (prod dependencies)

```
    "dependencies": {
        "grunt": "^0.4.1",
        "grunt-autoprefixer": "^0.7.3",
        "grunt-concurrent": "^0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.4.0",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.9.0",
        "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.3.0",
        "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.8.1",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.4.0",
        "grunt-filerev": "^0.2.1",
        "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.0",
        "grunt-newer": "^0.7.0",
        "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.3.0",
        "grunt-svgmin": "^0.4.0",
        "grunt-usemin": "^2.1.1",
        "grunt-wiredep": "^1.7.0",
        "jshint-stylish": "^0.2.0",
        "load-grunt-tasks": "^0.4.0",
        "time-grunt": "^0.3.1"
  },
```

**deployment.cmd** (some parts omitted for brevity)

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Deployment
:: ----------

:Deployment
echo Handling node.js deployment.

:: 1. Select node version
call :SelectNodeVersion

:: 2. Install bower packages
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\bower.json" (
  echo installing bower
  call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install -g bower
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  echo installing bower success
  popd
)

:: 3. Install Grunt
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\Gruntfile.js" (
  echo installing grunt-cli
  call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install -g grunt-cli
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  echo installing grunt-cli success
  popd
)

:: 4. Install npm packages
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\package.json" (
  echo installing npm packages
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
  call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install --production
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  echo installing npm packages 
  popd
)

:: 5. KuduSync
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)


:: Post deployment stub
IF DEFINED POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION ( 

  echo  "%POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION%"
  echo %0

  call :ExecuteCmd "%POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION%"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)
```

**I have 2 problems: As it stands my build is failing with the following error:**

> Error: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.

I believe grunt/some of its dependencies to be the be the culprit, but I don't know how to get past this roadblock. The way I understand how the dependency management work in node is that its a nested structure, each dependency will have its own `node_modules` folder... to infinity & beyond.

**Second problem**

> Looking for app.js/server.js under site root.
>
> Missing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated

I realize the app.js is not in the root. I believe it's easily fixed with a setting change, but I can only do it once the solution compiles on Azure, as the app.js will be sitting in a folder called `dist` that gets created once the compilation succeeds.

**Complete error log**

```
    Command: deploy.cmd
Using custom deployment setting for POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION custom value is 'grunt build'.
Handling node.js deployment.
Looking for app.js/server.js under site root.
Missing server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated
Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.17, 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.8.28, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32.
Selected node.js version 0.10.32. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
installing bower
C:\DWASFiles\Sites\~1businessintelligenceadviser\AppData\npm\bower -> C:\DWASFiles\Sites\~1businessintelligenceadviser\AppData\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower
bower@1.3.12 C:\DWASFiles\Sites\~1businessintelligenceadviser\AppData\npm\node_modules\bower
├── is-root@1.0.0
├── junk@1.0.0
├── stringify-object@1.0.0
├── abbrev@1.0.5
├── chmodr@0.1.0
├── which@1.0.5
├── osenv@0.1.0
├── archy@0.0.2
├── opn@1.0.0
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── bower-logger@0.2.2
├── lru-cache@2.5.0
├── bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.2
├── graceful-fs@3.0.4
├── lockfile@1.0.0
├── retry@0.6.0
├── nopt@3.0.1
├── tmp@0.0.23
├── request-progress@0.3.0 (throttleit@0.0.2)
├── q@1.0.1
├── shell-quote@1.4.2 (array-filter@0.0.1, array-reduce@0.0.0, array-map@0.0.0, jsonify@0.0.0)
├── chalk@0.5.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.2, ansi-styles@1.1.0, supports-color@0.2.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0, has-ansi@0.1.0)
├── semver@2.3.2
├── fstream@1.0.2 (inherits@2.0.1)
├── bower-json@0.4.0 (intersect@0.0.3, deep-extend@0.2.11, graceful-fs@2.0.3)
├── p-throttler@0.1.0 (q@0.9.7)
├��─ promptly@0.2.0 (read@1.0.5)
├── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── fstream-ignore@1.0.1 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@1.0.0)
├── bower-config@0.5.2 (osenv@0.0.3, graceful-fs@2.0.3, optimist@0.6.1)
├── tar-fs@0.5.2 (pump@0.3.5, tar-stream@0.4.7)
├── decompress-zip@0.0.8 (mkpath@0.1.0, nopt@2.2.1, touch@0.0.2, readable-stream@1.1.13, binary@0.3.0)
├── glob@4.0.6 (inherits@2.0.1, once@1.3.1, minimatch@1.0.0)
├── request@2.42.0 (caseless@0.6.0, json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, stringstream@0.0.4, oauth-sign@0.4.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, node-uuid@1.4.1, qs@1.2.2, mime-types@1.0.2, form-data@0.1.4, bl@0.9.3, tough-cookie@0.12.1, http-signature@0.10.0, hawk@1.1.1)
├── bower-registry-client@0.2.1 (graceful-fs@2.0.3, request-replay@0.2.0, lru-cache@2.3.1, async@0.2.10, mkdirp@0.3.5, request@2.27.0)
├── cardinal@0.4.0 (redeyed@0.4.4)
├── update-notifier@0.2.0 (semver-diff@0.1.0, string-length@0.1.2, latest-version@0.2.0, configstore@0.3.1)
├── mout@0.9.1
├── handlebars@2.0.0 (optimist@0.3.7, uglify-js@2.3.6)
├── inquirer@0.7.1 (figures@1.3.3, mute-stream@0.0.4, through@2.3.6, readline2@0.1.0, lodash@2.4.1, rx@2.3.14, cli-color@0.3.2)
└── insight@0.4.3 (object-assign@1.0.0, async@0.9.0, chalk@0.5.1, os-name@1.0.1, lodash.debounce@2.4.1, tough-cookie@0.12.1, configstore@0.3.1, inquirer@0.6.0)
installing bower success
installing grunt-cli
C:\DWASFiles\Sites\~1businessintelligenceadviser\AppData\npm\grunt -> C:\DWASFiles\Sites\~1businessintelligenceadviser\AppData\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt
grunt-cli@0.1.13 C:\DWASFiles\Sites\~1businessintelligenceadviser\AppData\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
├── resolve@0.3.1
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (glob@3.2.11, lodash@2.4.1)
installing grunt-cli success
installing npm packages
npm WARN package.json businessintelligenceadviser@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json businessintelligenceadviser@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json businessintelligenceadviser@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-gifsicle\node_modules\gifsicle\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\bin-check\node_modules\executable\node_modules\meow\node_modules\indent-string requires minimist@'^1.1.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-gifsicle\node_modules\gifsicle\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\bin-check\node_modules\executable\node_modules\meow\node_modules\indent-string\node_modules\repeating\node_modules\meow requires minimist@'^1.1.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\bin-version-check\node_modules\bin-version\node_modules\find-versions requires minimist@'^1.1.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\download\node_modules\decompress-tar requires vinyl@'^0.4.3' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
installing npm packages 
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\download\node_modules\decompress-tarbz2 requires vinyl@'^0.4.3' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\download\node_modules\decompress-targz requires vinyl@'^0.4.3' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\download\node_modules\decompress-unzip requires vinyl@'^0.4.3' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\download\node_modules\vinyl-fs requires vinyl@'^0.4.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-optipng\node_modules\optipng-bin\node_modules\bin-build\node_modules\download\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob2base requires lodash@'^2.4.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-optipng\node_modules\optipng-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\bin-check\node_modules\executable\node_modules\meow\node_modules\indent-string requires minimist@'^1.1.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-optipng\node_modules\optipng-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\bin-check\node_modules\executable\node_modules\meow\node_modules\indent-string\node_modules\repeating\node_modules\meow requires minimist@'^1.1.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-optipng\node_modules\optipng-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\bin-version-check\node_modules\bin-version\node_modules\find-versions requires minimist@'^1.1.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\.travis.yml'
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\CHANGELOG'
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-pngquant\node_modules\pngquant-bin\node_modules\bin-build\node_modules\download\node_modules\meow\node_modules\indent-string requires minimist@'^1.1.0' but will load
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\LICENSE-MIT'
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\package.json'
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\README.md'
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-pngquant\node_modules\pngquant-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\bin-check\node_modules\executable\node_modules\meow\node_modules\indent-string requires minimist@'^1.1.0' but will load
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\.bin\autoprefixer'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\.bin\autoprefixer.cmd'
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\ChangeLog.md'
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\LICENSE'
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-pngquant\node_modules\pngquant-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\bin-check\node_modules\executable\node_modules\meow\node_modules\indent-string\node_modules\repeating\node_modules\meow requires minimist@'^1.1.0' but will load
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\package.json'
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\README.md'
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\bin\autoprefixer'
npm WARN unmet dependency D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-pngquant\node_modules\pngquant-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\download\node_modules\meow\node_modules\indent-string requires minimist@'^1.1.0' but will load
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\data\browsers.js'
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\data\prefixes.js'
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\binary.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\caniuse.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\declaration.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\info.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\keyframes.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\old-selector.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\old-value.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\prefixer.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\prefixes.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\processor.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\selector.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\utils.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\value.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\align-content.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\align-items.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\align-self.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\background-size.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\border-image.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\border-radius.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\break-inside.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\display-flex.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\fill-available.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\filter.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\flex-basis.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\flex-direction.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\flex-flow.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\flex-grow.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\flex-shrink.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\flex-spec.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\flex-wrap.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\flex.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\fullscreen.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\grunt-autoprefixer\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\hacks\gradient.js'
Omitting next output lines...
Processed 975 files...
Error: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
Failed exitCode=1, command="kudusync" -v 50 -f "D:\home\site\repository" -t "D:\home\site\wwwroot" -n "D:\home\site\deployments\360cd39f800d7a19bf82bb41d4bd85830829a303\manifest" -p "D:\home\site\deployments\8ff648ca5da1071c0480e2ad3aa8a82eafeccb00\manifest" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path error is something I've run into as well with Grunt work. Seems to be a Windows issue and there aren't any easy/nice solutions.

One of the things we've done with our Grunt work is to heavily use symlinks in Windows. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx

For example, we install all Grunt dependencies in one directory, one time and then create symbolic links as part of the build to that one directory. That might help overcome the long directory/filename issue.

Not perfectly clear on the second issue, but mklink might be able to help there as well if a file exists somewhere else.